# dynamically resize custom form[submit] with CSS as the browser width/height changes?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, resize, submit

It seems easy to dynamically resize images with CSS. If I try this with a custom submitbutton, the submit button apears very small.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submitID">
</form>
```

-

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%; width:100%;}

#submitID{
  background:url(../images/button.png);
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS background image won't stretch.

How about a BUTTON containing an IMG tag:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submitID">
  <img src="" />
</button>
```

Then you can control the size of the IMG tag instead.